# How to Create A jQuery URL Redirect Based On Dropdown Selection Without Using Select ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Thanks in advance for your help with this! :)

I need to redirect visitors to different urls when they click the submit button, based on the option they select in a dropdown.

But the difficulty I have is that I'm forced to use a website builder that doesn't let me modify the html. But it does let me add javascript code to the page. So the solution needs to be exclusively javascript/jQuery.

So I need to use javascript or jQuery to create the url redirect, based on the selected option in a dropdown (that doesn't have a selection id). Take a look at the code below.

**Here's the HTML for the dropdown:**

```
<div class="de elInputWrapper elSelectFormBox de-editable de-input-block elAlign_center elMargin0" id="tmp_select_input-89382" data-de-type="select-input" data-de-editing="false" data-title="select input form" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade" data-delay="500" type="custom_type" style="margin-top: 10px; outline: none; cursor: pointer;">
<label class="elInputLabel">

<select name="custom_type" class="elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight required0 elInput-Select1" data-type="extra" data-custom-type="Dropdown">
<option value="I want to...">I want to...</option>
<option value="Refinance">Refinance</option>
<option value="Purchase a home I found">Purchase a home I found</option>
<option value="Get pre-approved for a mortgage">Get pre-approved for a mortgage</option>

</select>
</label>
</div>
```

**Here's the HTML for the button:**

I can change the href on the button.

```
<div class="de elBTN elMargin0 elAlign_left de-editable" id="tmp_button-92288-160" data-de-type="button" data-de-editing="false" data-title="button" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade" data-delay="500" style="margin-top: 0px; outline: none; cursor: pointer; display: block; font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;" data-google-font="Lato">
<a href="#" class="elButton elButtonSize1 elButtonColor1 elButtonFluid elButtonPadding2 elButtonRounded elButtonNoShadow" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(121, 172, 50); font-size: 23px;">
<span class="elButtonMain">Let's Go!</span>
<span class="elButtonSub"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

**And here's the jQuery code I'm currently trying to use:**

```
<script src=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js'‌>
console.log('hey-OutsideClickFunction');
/*Redirect based on Dropdown selection*/
$("#tmp_button-92288-160").click(function(){ 
console.log('hey-InsideClickFunction');
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Refinance')
{
window.location ='http://bing.com';
}
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Purchase a home I found')
{
window.location ="http://google.com";
}    
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Get pre-approved for a mortgage')
{
window.location ="http://yahoo.com";
}      
document.getElementById("tmp_select_input-89382").click(); 
})
</script>
```

**Additional jQuery Attempts**

I also tried replacing `$("#tmp_select_input-89382").attr("action","yahoo.com");` with `$(location).attr('href', 'yahoo.com');` and with `window.location.href = "http://yahoo.com";` and with `window.location = "http://yahoo.com";`

With all of these, the page just reloads when I click the button.

**Javascript Code I Tried To Use**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("#tmp_button-92288-160").addEventListener("click",‌ function(){
var option = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
if(option.value =="Refinance"){
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");}
else if(option.value =="Purchase a home I found"){
window.open("https://youtube.com/");}
else{window.open("http://www.bing.com/");
}}
</script>
```

But the page just reloads when I click the button.

Comment: `document.getElementById("tmp_select_input-89382")` is a div how can you submit a div

Comment: I'm new to this... I'm not a programmer... How would you solve it @AatifBandey? .. I appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: and remove `#` from document.getElementById("#tmp_select_input-89382").submit`

Comment: `document.getElementById("tmp_select_input-89382").click()` try this

Comment: did you try ? the above solution

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. The page doesn't redirect. Thank you though! :)

Comment: I also tried changing  $("#tmp_select_input-89382").attr("action","http://yahoo.com"); with $(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com')

Comment: try the solution below

Comment: try below fiddle see if it helps you.
https://jsfiddle.net/mandar_ranade/5mproaoo/

Second approach

https://jsfiddle.net/mandar_ranade/5mproaoo/1/

Comment: @Mandy Hi! So the difficulty I have is that I'm forced to use a website builder. And it created the dropdown, but didn't add "selection id=". So I can't use the selection id. Also, it created the dropdown, but it doesn't allow me to add a url as a value. So I need to use javascript or jQuery to select the url, based on the selected option in a dropdown that doesn't have a selection id. Take a look at the code in the original question, and you'll see why I'm having difficulty. Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: @ChrisECG does it add any spl class or do you have it's immediate parent?
Your dropdown has "Name" attribute. if it's unique you can use that too. you can replace #id code with name.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `window.location` method

```
 $("#tmp_button-92288-160").click(function() {

  if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Refinance')
  {
   window.location ='http://bing.com'
  }
  if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Purchase a home I found')
  {
   window.location ="http://google.com";
  }    
  if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Get pre-approved for a       mortgage')
  {
   window.location ="http://yahoo.com";
  }      
   document.getElementById("tmp_select_input-89382").click(); 

 }
```

Comment: Tried it. But the page just reloads when I click the button. I've edited my original question to include the things I've attempted.

Comment: use # for href `<a href='#'>`

Comment: It should not reload the page

Comment: If you want to prevent reload 
`<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>`

Comment: changed href to #, and now the page scrolls to the top when I click on the button

Comment: did you try `<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>`

Comment: That's html code, so I can't add it. I'm forced to use a website builder that doesn't allow me to edit/add those attributes. :(  That's why I'm trying to inject jQuery to solve the issue.

Comment: can you change the click event on `$('.elButtonMain).click(function(){})`

Comment: Yes! I can add jQuery code to the page. So I should be able to change the click event on `$('.elButtonMain).click(function(){})`

Comment: Yes so `a` tag wont trigger

Comment: Did it help you ?

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot edit the html one of the solution for your answer can be
`$('.elButtonMain).click(function(){})`

Comment: I updated the code in the original question to show you how I tried to implement your suggestion. It continues to exhibit the same behavior as before; it scrolls to the top when I click the button.

Comment: remove `document.getElementById("tmp_select_input-89382").click();` form the function and test

Comment: Removed it, and still does the same thing.

Comment: did you try ` event.stopImmediatePropagation()` so not to trigger `<a>` tag
try it before if condition.

Comment: also did you print `console.log($('select[name=custom_type]').val())` ?

Comment: I just learned what console.log is! Thank you! ;) ...I updated the question to show you how I implemented it. The console log didn't print any value.

Comment: did you check the value inside your Developer tool (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools ) and if does not print anything that means none of your if condition will execute.

Comment: I saw you have written the function in `data-custom-js` attribute and also your console.log should be inside the click function
`$('#tmp_button-92288-160').click(function(e){console.log($('select[name=custom_type]').val())})`

Comment: Not printing anything... I updated the question to show how I implemented the console.log inside the click function

Comment: no need to have three or four functions just keep one  remove others `/*Console.log*/  
console.log($('select[name=custom_type]').val());  
$('#tmp_button-92288-160').click(function(e){console.log($('‌select[name=custom_t‌ype]').val())});

/*Stop Propagating*/  
$('.elButtonMain').click(function(){});
$("#tmp_button-92288-160").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});` update your question

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: check what does it print now, does it prin `undefined` or `emty` `/*Console.log*/  
  

/*Redirect based on Dropdown selection*/
$("#tmp_button-92288-160").click(function() { 
console.log($('select[name=custom_type]').val());
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Refinance')
{
window.location ='http://bing.com';
}
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Purchase a home I found')
{
window.location ="http://google.com";
}    
if($('select[name=custom_type]').val() == 'Get pre-approved for a mortgage')
{
window.location ="http://yahoo.com";
}      

}`

Comment: Doesn't print anything

Comment: try this and check what does it print 
`console.log($( 'select[name="custom_type"]' ).val();)`

Comment: your console.log should be inside the click function please dont bring it outside

Comment: ok, thanks! Updated the code on the page, and updated it in the original question. Still doesn't print anything... Thank you for all of your help! You're amazing! :)

Comment: ok inside the click function just print `console.log('hey')` does it print anything after you click the button `Lets Go`

Comment: I hope you were checking the prints after you click the button `Lets Go` on your site

Comment: I changed it to `console.log('hey');` and it still doesn't print anything after I click the button

Comment: Yes, I was checking the prints before and after I clicked the button ;)

Comment: I also tried placing `console.log('hey'); outside the click function, and it still didn't print.

Comment: Y does your console throws  this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token   VM194:1`

Comment: and why are you writing your js in the attribute `data-custom-js` why cant you write separately at the bottom or start of your html page

Comment: I can add the code into the header or footer. That's fine. I moved it into the header. ... I'm looking through the console to see if I find anything. Console alerted me about a missing `)` and I added that into the jQuery. Now I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error "$ is not defined"

Comment: Now it printed 'hey'! :) But I created 2 prints. it only printed the 'hey' I placed outside the click function. It still isn't printing the 'hey-InsideClickFunction'

Comment: Ok  have you included jquery in your page ? if not 
`<script src='
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js'></script>` the reason for `$` not defined was jquery missing

Comment: This error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` on row 1 seems to be caused because the page has an ssl certificate, but it is loading unsecured images from http://. This is creating an error due to mixed content, and this error is showing up because those images don't have ssl tokens. But the error appears on row 1 because the SSL loads before everything else on the page.

Comment: So I have another jQuery script running already, and it works, but it's placed in a custom-js element in the body. So perhaps the page is loading jQuery after the custom header code... Anyways, I added the library the way you explained, and it removed the `$` error, but now a new error is showing that says "defined is not defined"

Comment: included latest jQuery in question

Comment: And by adding the library, it stopped printing 'hey-OutsideClickFunction'... If I remove the `src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js'‌` then it prints again.

Comment: put it in header `<script src=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js'‌​></script>` then check

Comment: updated question. all of the code is in the header. It stops printing 'hey-OutsideClickFunction' and it gives error `define is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

A quick example in pure Javascript:

```
<select id="sex">
<option value="val1">variant one</option>
<option value="val2">variant two</option>
<option value="val3">variant three</option>
</select>

<button  type="submit" onclick="navigate()">
Press me
</button>

function navigate(){

var option = document.getElementById("sex");
if(option.value =="val1"){
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}else if(option.value =="val2"){
window.open("https://youtube.com/");
}else{
window.open("http://www.bing.com/");
}}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxytL032/

Comment: Great suggestion! Now, one of the problems I have is that the dropdown doesn't have an element id, and I can't edit the HTML to add an id. So can you take a look at the code in the question, and help me figure out how to reference the dropdown without using the element id? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChrisECG if the <select> element doesn't have an id, you select him by tag name. Write like this : document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]; This targets the 1st <select> element you have in the page.

Comment: Since I can't edit the HTML, I can't add the `onclick="navigate()"` to the button. Is there a way to use javascript to add this attribute to the button?

Comment: @ChrisECG  yes, you can add an event listener through javascript. You need to write : `document.getElementById("butonID").addEventListener("click",function(){ // the rest of code i sugested })`

Comment: I tried implementing it, but the page just reloads. I edited the original question to include the Javascript code I tried to use. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop propagating the event to child element `<a>`

`$("#tmp_button-92288-160").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: Added this to the code (see the code update in the original question). Same result. Page reloads.